# Use of Group and roles in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to HDFS, 
When i run hadoop fs -ls /tmp/data command , I get the below output
 
-rw-r--r--   2 root root      52784 2014-08-01 09:52 /tmp/data/sample1.pdf
-rw-r--r--   2 root root      52784 2014-08-01 09:52 /tmp/data/Sample2.pdf

From this output i wanna know 
Which is the Group? and What is the use of the Group ?
Which is the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st root is the user , 2nd root is the group.

Group is used to group all users under it so as to restrict access to hdfs directories based on the groups.

Comment: You may also be interested in the [Apache Hadoop hdfs permissions guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html).

Comment: @K S Nidhin : How to create a Group and map users to it ? . Could you please provide some brief details of it .

Comment: " -rw-r--r-- " , What does this mean ?

Comment: K S Nidhin : drwxr-xr-x   - root root          0 2014-08-14 03:20 /user/Mainclass_B ....I have a two users user1 and user2 . I want to make user1 as the owner of the Mainclass_B such that user2 should not be able to read/write/access it .But a root user should be able to access it . How can i achieve this ? .